# How to output logs with python logging in a click cli?

Tags: python, logging, click, command-line-interface

I've written a python cli with the 'click' library. I'd like to also use python's built-in `logging` module for logging to the console. But I've struggled getting the logging messages to the console. I tried a very simple approach:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

@click.command()
def cli():
    logger.setLevel("INFO")
    logger.info("Does this work?")
    print("done.")
```

The logger content doesn't appear in my console. Maybe it needs a handler to explicitly send log messages to stdout?

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

@click.command()
def cli():
    handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(message)s'))
    handler.setLevel("INFO")
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    logger.info("Does this work?")
    print("done.")
```

Unfortunately this also doesn't work.

A third option--creating a handler and setting loglevels for the handler and the logger-- works:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

@click.command()
def cli():
    logger.setLevel("INFO")
    handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stderr)
    handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(message)s'))
    handler.setLevel("INFO")
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    logger.info("Does this work?")
    print("done.")
```

It seems like:

- if creating a logger with `logging.getLogger`, I have to create a handler for my logger explicitly.
- and I have to set a loglevel on **both** the logger and the handler?

Is that right? It seems silly to set the level twice. What's the point?

Or am I still misunderstanding the right way to do this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 9):

I personally like the `loguru` library for handling logs.  I think it's simpler.

Here's an example of how I usually do it:

```py
import click
from loguru import logger


@click.command()
@click.option('--count', default=1, help='Number of greetings.')
@click.option('--name', prompt='Your name', help='The person to greet.')
def hello(count, name):
    """Simple program that greets NAME for a total of COUNT times."""
    for x in range(count):
        logger.info(f"That's it, beautiful and simple logging! - Counter: {x}")
        click.echo('Hello %s!' % name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    hello()
```

```
❯ python loguru-click-cli-test.py --count=3
Your name: Geraldo
2020-06-10 20:02:48.297 | INFO     | __main__:hello:11 - That's it, beautiful and simple logging! - Counter: 0
Hello Geraldo!
2020-06-10 20:02:48.297 | INFO     | __main__:hello:11 - That's it, beautiful and simple logging! - Counter: 1
Hello Geraldo!
2020-06-10 20:02:48.297 | INFO     | __main__:hello:11 - That's it, beautiful and simple logging! - Counter: 2
Hello Geraldo!
```

Loguru: https://github.com/Delgan/loguru

Answer (score 7):

I had to manually set

```py
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
```

Example

```py
import click
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

@click.command()
def cli():
    logging.info("it works")
```

gives

```sh
$ mycli
INFO:root:it works
```

Comment: Use `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(message)s')` to get output without `"INFO:root:"`

Answer (score 2):

I was looking to get logs when a click handler is called (command name and parameters). I end up with this snippet:

```py
from functools import wraps
import logging
import click

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def click_log(fn):
    @wraps(fn)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        context = click.get_current_context()
        logger.info(f"{context.command.name}(**{context.params})")
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@click.command()
@click.option('--count', default=1, help='Number of greetings.')
@click.option('--name', prompt='Your name',
              help='The person to greet.')
@click_log
def hello(count, name):
    """Simple program that greets NAME for a total of COUNT times."""
    for x in range(count):
        click.echo(f"Hello {name}!")  # you can use logger.info


def configure_logger():
    logging.basicConfig(level="DEBUG")

configure_logger()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    hello()
```

It gives you the following output:

```
python test_click.py --count 3
Your name: ok
INFO:__main__:hello(**{'count': 3, 'name': 'ok'})
Hello ok!
Hello ok!
Hello ok!
```